# Seeing remote directory of files when using local ArcGIS server manager session to remote server?

Tags: arcgis-server

Here is my setup -

AWS cluster for my ArcGIS Server instance with SD files copied to it

Currently I have to open a remote session and launch the AGS manager from the cluster so I can point to the files I copied over.

What I would like is to be able to open an AGS manager window on my local machine and point to the files already copied up. Any thoughts how I could navigate to the remote server's local paths?